# Como hago una subconsulta dentro de UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tengo un problema en mysql y es el siguente, resulta que tengo que actualizar como trayecto corto todo lo que dure menos de 3 horas, hice esta consulta

```
UPDATE reservas
SET trayecto = 'corto'
WHERE 3 < (
        SELECT
            HOUR(TIMEDIFF(fin_alquiler, incio_alquiler)) AS 'Diferencia'
        FROM reservas
);
```

Pero me da un error de que no puedo especificar la tabla reservas para actualizar con FROM. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por el código que muestras no necesitas una subconsulta. Algo como esto alcanzaría: UPDATE reservas SET trayecto = 'corto' WHERE  HOUR(TIMEDIFF(fin_alquiler, incio_alquiler) < 3

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias, era eso lo que tenia mal! Gracias.